# React Hooks & UseEffect not updating display with socketIO data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks, use-effect

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import socketIO from 'socket.io-client';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

function Sock() {
   const [textData, setTextData] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      const socket = socketIO('http://127.0.0.1:5009');
      socket.on('chat message', (text)  =>  {
         setTextData([
             textData.push(text)
          ]);
      console.log(textData);
      });
   },[]);

  return (
     <Container>
        <h1>Socket</h1>
        <li>{textData}</li>
     </Container>
  ); 
}

export default Sock;
```

The initial return does an initial render and displays everything. but then does not re render when incoming data from the socket. It console logs everything fine.

I am fairly new to hooks, I have already achieved this doing it the class way but am currently refactoring the app to use hooks instead. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React doesn't understand that textData changed because you don't change reference on array. You can try this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import socketIO from 'socket.io-client';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

function Sock() {
   const [textData, setTextData] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      const socket = socketIO('http://127.0.0.1:5009');
      socket.on('chat message', (text)  =>  {
         setTextData([
             ...textData,
             ...text,
         ]);
         console.log(textData);
      });
   },[textData]);

  return (
     <Container>
        <h1>Socket</h1>
        {textData.map((text) => <li>{text}</li>)}
     </Container>
  ); 
}

export default Sock;
```

But why do you want to set handler on socket every time your `textData` will change? So, i think you should not pass `[textData]` to useEffect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. is there a typo on: setTextData([
             ...textData,
             text,

Comment: @davidmichael ohh, i can't find the typo for 5 minutes :(

Comment: @davidmichael you are right, it happens because you try to print array `textData` into `li`. It's mistake if elem of `textData` is an object. React can't print ReactNote only and objects are not react nodes.

Comment: @davidmichael can you show `console.log(textData)` before return statement?

Comment: Cheers I have got it working some what. just need to fiddle about with it @SaveliTomac

Comment: My Mistake it is now rendering to screen but just the amount of objects in the array. Ive updated my original post @SaveliTomac

Comment: @davidmichael you should create new question in this case, but I try to help you here

Comment: @davidmichael so, can you show result of console.log?

Comment: Array [ {…} ]
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
...
​The array increments after every socket update. Inside the array is: 0: {…}
​​
Device: 1
​​
DeviceName: "Device 1"
​​
Id: 1
​​
Input: 1
​​
InputName: "Input 1"
​​
InputState: 1
​​
OffPhrase: "Off"
​​
OnPhrase: "On"
​​
When: "2019-12-17T13:50:09.0823784+00:00"

Comment: @davidmichael is the text in your socket callback it array?

Comment: Yes it is. Socket.on(event, callback) - Taken from the official docs

Comment: Same result I am afraid. its just printing out total objects in the array @SaveliTomac

Comment: @davidmichael not only printing, i destructed text in callback too

Comment: just to confirm in your answer `setTextData([
             ...textData,
             ...text,
         ]);`   I have implemented that as  `setTextData([
            textData.push(text)
        ]);`

Comment: According to your words `text` it's array too and you get nested array if you don't destruct it

Comment: @davidmichael i think you should create new answer and give me a link, comments is not a place for it

Comment: I have created a new question @SaveliTomac here is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376486/react-hooks-useeffect-not-updating-display-with-socketio-data-only-renders-el cheers