# React Hooks & UseEffect not updating display with socketIO data. Only renders elements in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import socketIO from 'socket.io-client';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';


function Sock() {
   const [textData, setTextData] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      const socket = socketIO('http://127.0.0.1:5009');
      socket.on('chat message', (text)  =>  {
         setTextData([
            textData.push(text)
         ]);
         console.log(textData);
      });
   },[]);

  return (
      <Container>
         <h1>Socket</h1>
            {textData.map((text) => <li>{text}</li>)}
      </Container>
  ); 
}

export default Sock;
```

With help I have managed to display something on the UI but it currently only displays the array count and not the object inside the array. I am fairly new to React hooks any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join your *data* (text) with existing *data* (textData), try with:

```
setTextData([...textData, text]);
```

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot. I will set as the answer @moseRaguzzini

Answer (score 4):

There are [few ways to take care of stale closure](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#what-happens-when-dependencies-lie) but for your simple case, you can use the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) syntax to get the previous text data, and return a new instance of array (do not mutate existing state, using `push`).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIO("http://127.0.0.1:5009");
    socket.on("chat message", text => {
      setTextData(previousTextData => [...previousTextData, text]);
    });
  }, []);
```

Using the callback approach, you don't need to put `textData` in the `useEffect`'s dependency array.

Comment: It's good answer. But i would clarify `Array.push` returns a size of an array. So, author of question got it in his view.

Comment: The OP's intention was to use the `text` within the returned element `{textData.map((text) => <li>{text}</li>)}` thus I expected him to store list of texts in the state, not the count.

Comment: You're not understand. Your code works fine, but you didn't explain why OP got a number in his view. It's happen because `Array.push` returns a size of an array and OP try to render it in his component.